# How to ensure that a particular thread finishes execution first and the other last?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

So say there are 3 threads (t1, t2, t3) spawned off the main thread. How would I ensure that a particular thread finishes its execution first and another thread as last. I don't mean to begin a thread after the "completion" of another, but want to ensure they **finish in a particular order**.

A sample code will be extremely helpful.

To be more precise, say in a gaming application, you would want to change the graphics first, then you want the sound to be produced followed by the score update.

Comment: You can't do that.  The best you can do is create a "checkpoint" where all threads finish.  C.f. `CyclicBarrier` and `CountDownLatch`.

Comment: Why? It depends entirely on how long they take and whether there are semaphore-like interactions between them. If none, the finishing order is indeterminate.

Comment: It just occured to me to ask *why* you want a guaranteed thread termination order. Without more details, it's starting to look more and more like a [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)...

Comment: Please share with us your actual problem. You would not (i.e. *should not*) spawn a thread just to update the score *once* on a game...

Comment: you can use wait() notify()

Answer (score 0):

You may use `wait()` and `notify()`. It is a mechanism through which we can send signals between threads.

`wait()`causes the thread to pause in the critical region. While paused the thread releases its lock. It must be called inside synchronization block or method.

`notify()` will send signal to one of the threads waiting for the same object.. It wakes up the thread that have called notify().

Here is an example with two of your functions: display and sound. Display would be completed before sound:

(You may add third one (score) also.)

```
class shared
{
    synchronized void disp()
    {
        System.out.println("Display thread complete");

        notify();
    }
    synchronized void play_s()
    {
        try
        {
            wait();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie)
        {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Sound thread complete");
    }


}
class display extends Thread
{
    shared sh;
    public display(shared sh,String str)
    {
        super(str);
        this.sh=sh;
        start();
    }
    public void run()
    {
        sh.disp();
    }

}

class sound extends Thread

{
    shared sh;
    public sound(shared sh,String str)
    {
        super(str);
        this.sh=sh;
        start();
    }
    public void run()
    {
        sh.play_s();
    }

}

public class sync {

    public static void main(String agrs[])
    {
        shared sh=new shared();
        display d=new display(sh,"one");
        sound s=new sound(sh,"two");

    }

}
```

Comment: Uh, did you actually try this? On my system the display thread finishes so fast, that the sound thread gets stuck forever waiting for a notification that never comes...

Comment: duh! so sorry.. let me check.. the code should work.. I edited the code I had, for this answer, maybe I forgot something..
you may edit the answer if there's a minor mistake somewhere.. :)

Comment: Nivedita: quite honestly, it would probably need an overhaul to work correctly, not to mention that adding that third thread is *not* trivial. There is a reason lock objects where added to Java...

Comment: I agree with thkala, this code needs an overhaul. In particular, `wait` is misused; it should not be used to wait until another thread notifies this one. Instead, `wait` should wait until a condition is true or until the object reaches a desired state.

Comment: in that case can we use a boolean variable to determine wheather to run the sound and other threads or not? should I edit the answer? or remove it?

Answer (score 0):

"To be more precise, say in a gaming application, you would want to change the graphics first, then you want the sound to be produced followed by the score update."

That requires sequential execution of the externally visible activities. The graphics update has to happen in the event handling thread, and that seems to be the obvious place to sequence the activities.

I would separate out any computationally intensive or otherwise time consuming preparations for each activity, and delegate it to a thread or thread pool, without worrying about order. Use e.g. invokeLater to notify the event handling thread when the computation has been done. In the event handling thread, keep track of the conditions for doing something, such as changing the score. When all conditions have been met, including completion of all pre-conditions, do the action.

Comment: I am not sure that a game is what the OP is working on - if it is, then they are doing something really strange. They should be focusing on parallelizing the various processes and data flows correctly, using the concurrency infrastructure to handle any interdependencies. Why worry about thread *termination* at all?

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn’t make much sense as the finishing of a thread has no impact on the state of the application and hence, the finishing order is completely irrelevant as well. It’s very likely that what you are actually trying to achieve needs a different solution.

This is illustrated by your example: “say in a gaming application, you would want to change the graphics first, then you want the sound to be produced followed by the score update”. Here you are describing actions that you want to be *performed* one after another, which entirely contradicts your statement “I don't mean to begin a thread after the "completion" of another”.

What you probably meant is that you want to load or calculate resources, e.g. graphics and sound, concurrently but want to render them in order. Therefore the key point is to split the loading/calculation from the rendering into two dependent tasks. Then, while the graphic rendering task only depends on the completion of the graphics creation, the sound rendering depends on both, the sound data creation and the completion of the graphics rendering, to establish your desired order. So it’s not the finishing of the sound thread that depends on the finishing of the graphics thread but it’s the *beginning* of the sound rendering that depends on the finishing of the graphics rendering.

There are a lot of ways to implement such things but given how abstract your question is, it’s way too broad.

However, regarding your original question, there is [`Thread.join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()). When the code executed by thread `T2` invokes that method on thread `T1` it will wait for the termination of `T1`, thus the thread `T2` will not terminate before `T1`. But, as said, placing such a wait at the end of `T2` would not make much sense as the finishing order of the threads is meaningless. You would have to place it *before* the beginning of the dependent action.

Comment: Well on the contradiction part: "Beginning a thread" means starting a thread which is different from repeating the task. If I mentioned a gaming application you should've understood it by yourself. I do understand the point of multithreading, but for the purpose of learning and to get the insight of how things actually work under the hood, people come up with certain questions. By the way thanks for the solution, I cameup with that already.

Comment: @rsb: You didn’t ask a question about “how things actually work under the hood” so what’s the point of your comment? The terms *beginning* and *finishing* are invariably defined as relationship to the activity between them. And ordering the finishing just makes no sense.